# Splitting a light wave

Tags: visible-light, interferometry

What I want to ask is what would happen if you split a single light ray (a photon) into two using a half silvered mirror? Would the emerging light rays have half the amplitude as the original one or half the frequency of the original wave?

Basically will the frequency get distributed or the amplitude?

**EDIT**

I specifically mean a "Single" photon or a single light ray. For those who think a single photon cannot be split, you are wrong. A photon has been split by using special crystals. It is called [Parametric down conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion).

Comment: A quantum can be destroyed, and two quanta of half the original energy created, but a half-silvered mirror does not do this.  "Single light ray" is not a meaningful phrase in conventional optics language.

Answer (score 3):

If you reduce the intensity of the light beam so that effectively you know you only have one photon in the apparatus at a time, then what is observed will depend how it is observed.
In all cases though, the detected light (photons) will have *the same frequency*.

If you set up a detector so that it records the arrival of photons (note, you cannot have half a photon) in each possible direction, those detectors will each record half the number of photons (of the same frequency) that are injected into the apparatus. So if you refer to intensity in terms of *average* energy per second, then yes, the intensity is halved. But each photon definitely goes one way or the other and behaves *like a particle*. It is therefore difficult to discuss what happens to the amplitude, but if you define this as the square root of intensity, it is divided by $\sqrt{2}$.

However (and this why a lot of us study physics). If you set up some mirrors so that you can bring the two beams together again, *without* attempting to detect which arm the photon travelled down, then you can record an interference pattern. An example is [discussed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler's_delayed_choice_experiment). Thus in this case it appears the photon has travelled both paths simultaneously, like a wave, with equal amplitude in each arm.

Comment: I think you somewhat misinterpreted my question. What I really meant was what would be the emergent waves like on splitting a single light wave. Will the new waves have half the frequency or half the amplitude? Please read the edit in my question.

Comment: As I say, the frequency is unchanged (using a mirror). Half the amplitude would mean quarter the intensity, so this never happens.

Answer (score 0):

Within the terms you're using, the beam splitter will appear to randomly send a single photon in one direction or another. Over the long run, a 50% beam splitter will send half the photons in each path. The individual photons will be unchanged in energy/frequency/wavelength, so far as the term "unchanged" is meaningful in this situation. After all, if you intercept a photon to examine it, it cannot then propagate to the splitter.

Answer (score -2):

To answer the question = 'neither' .. any (each) detector (after the half silvered mirror) will only ever 'see' either a single 'complete' photon or none ..

One way to 'imagine' this, is to think of a travelling 'probability packet' .. the half silvered mirror splits a single photon (single 'packet') into a pair of entangled 'halves', each half containing half the 'probability'

We can assume** each half has the same everything else but can't measure that because on arrival at (any) detector, the ENTIRE entangled probability function is resolved - in this case we have two parts physically seperate, so when the probability coin is tossed, heads the (whole) photon arrives at one place, tails it's at the other ....

**Actually, we can use mirrors to recombine the two halves to generate interferrence patturns. If we do so, and use equations to 'predict' the patturn, the equations only 'work' correctly (predict the oputcome) if we assume each half retaines the same frequency / wavelength (which means both 'havles' have the same energy = which doesn't require energy to be created because each half is 'only half there' :-) )

Comment: Any reason for all the single-quote marks over the place here?